# Does parent controller get re-initialized again while navigating between child tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a parent controller and two tabs within it, each having its own controller as shown in image below:
[Parent and Child View Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqJqj.png)

I am broadcasting an event from Tab1/Tab2 controllers using $rootScope and catching it directive's controller scope using $scope. When I am switching between tabs, the parent controller and the directive's controller are getting initialized again and the event is caught twice in directive's controller even though it is broadcasted just once. 
I tried to debug and noticed the directive's controller $id when it was being caught. When the event was caught first time, the directive's id was the one which got created with previous tab(tab from which i switched). And second time, directive's id was the one which got created with current tab (tab to which i switched).

Note: 1) Even after using reload: false option, parent controller and directive controller is getting re-initialized.
2) I am not initializing parent controller by using ng-controller in html. It is getting initialized only via $stateProvider routing.

This is how i configured my states:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('app.parent', {
    url: 'parent/:paramId',
    params: {
      paramId: 'sample'
    },
    views: {
      'content-parent@app': {
        templateUrl: 'parent.html',
        controller: 'ParentController',
        resolve: {
          defaultParams: function(parentService, $stateParams) {
            return parentService.getDefaultParams($stateParams.paramId);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.parent.tab1', {
    url: '/tab1/',
    views: {
      'content-child@app.parent': {
        templateUrl: 'tab1.html',
        controller: 'Tab1Controller'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.parent.tab2', {
    url: '/tab2/',        
    views: {
      'content-child@app.parent': {
        templateUrl: 'tab2.html',
        controller: 'Tab2Controller'
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No, the parent state (and thus controller/component) is not re-initialized when the child states are changed. This includes any `resolve` functions and state event handlers associated with the parent state.

[Here's a Plunker that illustrates that the parent scope remains the same when you navigate between child states.](http://plnkr.co/edit/cqNuomKuIvZms98h5g8Y)

You can force it to reload the parent though, by setting the `reload` option of `$state.go(..)` to `true`. Like this:

```
$state.go('parent.childA', null, { reload: true });
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolaj! I noticed that reload is set to true to switch the tabs. But even after setting it to false or removing reload option also, the parent controller is getting re-initialized. Can there be any other reason because of which this is happening?

Comment: Can you share the code where you define your state configuration?

Comment: I have mentioned my state configuration in question description.

Comment: can you suggest some solution?

Comment: I can't find anything particularly wrong with what you've shared so far. Try recreating the issue in a Plunker or similar, then I'll play around with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The parent State remains unchanged as long as you do not push the changes to the parent controller using emit.

Here is [a c-sharpcorner link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/pass-data-from-parent-controller-to-child-controller) that might help you!